# Maven: trigger custom command when Build is finished, dependent on outcome (successful/failed)

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

I'm using Maven on the command line, and my build takes a while to complete (1-2min). 
I'm looking for a possibility to hook into the END of the build and trigger a specific command (start a program by ant, etc.) when the build is finished - dependent to the outcome of my build (Successful/Failed).

My goal is that my computer just plays a sound (one for successful build, another for a failed build) so i'll notice that my build is done.

Can i realize that, and how?
I guess Ant would be a possibility, but i hope i can also do it without Ant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should get you started.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>
                            import java.io.File;
                            import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
                            import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
                            import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
                            import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
                            File soundFile = new File("audio/beep.wav");
                            AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
                            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class,sound.getFormat());
                            Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
                            clip.open(sound);
                            clip.start();
                            sleep(5000);                        
                        </source>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

You'll want this Maven repository.

```
<repository>
    <id>org.codehaus.repository</id>
    <name>Codehaus repository</name>
    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: how to get if build is successful or a failure ?

Answer (score 7):

Here's a little script (for Windows) some of our dev's use that simply changes the bg colour of the cmd prompt, again utilizing the exit code.

```
@echo off

color 07

call mvn %*

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto RedBuild
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 goto GreenBuild

:RedBuild
color 4F
goto TheEnd

:GreenBuild
color 2F

:TheEnd
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the thought-provoking impulses!
As i'm on Windows, i realized it with a Batch script, which calls a little Java Program. This program triggers an action (showing a big green/red JPanel, playing a sound) according to the given ErrorLevel.

Instead of calling `mvn compile` etc., i now call `m compile`

m.bat:

```
@echo off
call mvn %*
start javaw -cp "D:\Workspace\Java\BuildInfo\bin" BuildInfo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Works perfect. Now i don't have to look at the console no more to see if my build is done!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get notified then https://github.com/jcgay/maven-notifier may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Finally made it to work with BurntToast, this project's documentation needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that like most good command-line tools, [the exit code](http://www.faqs.org/docs/abs/HTML/exit-status.html) returned from `mvn` when it terminates reflects if the build was successful or not. In other words, `mvn` returns a 1 when the build is successful and a 0 when it fails (you'll need to look up the specifics to be sure).

If this is so, you can write a custom batch/shell script which merely wraps the `mvn` command, passing any arguments received to the `mvn` command (so you can run `mymvn compile` and `mymvn clean deploy site` just as easily).

Your custom wrapper script can then invoke whatever command is necessary to play a sound based on the return code from `mvn`.

Comment: Exit code is a good idea, and according to the Maven `Invoker` docs (http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/usage.html), Maven is indeed well-behaved this way.

Comment: A good approach, but note that a 0 is actually the return code for correct termination, anything non-zero denotes an error http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status Please update your answer accordingly.